# Select animated bones only in pose mode

Tags: animation, pose-mode

I want to flip a pose but I don't want to add keyframes to non-animated bones from selecting all and copying and pasting the pose. I just want the animated ones only to be mirrored, was wondering if there was a quicker way to select the bones in the armature that are keyed without selecting each one manually.